# How do I read this probability formula

Tags: probability

I am reading some documentation which looks like:

```
p(0) = P(0 successes in n trials) = (1-p)n {FFFFFFF}
p(1) = P(1 success in n trials) = (n 1)p(1-p)n-1 {FSFFFFF}
p(2) = P(2 successes in n trials) = (n 2)p2(1-p)n-2 {FSFSFFF}
```

how do I interpret the parts that look like (n 1) and (n 2). I'm guessing you do not multiply it

Answer (score 6):

It's the binomial coefficient $\tbinom nk$, read as n-choose-k:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient